# Assign new property to empty object which has frozen prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, ecmascript-5

Why can't I assign new properties to non-frozen object, which has frozen prototype:

Working without Object.freeze:

```
'use strict'
//This object will be prototype of next objects
var defaults = {
  name: 'def name', 
  sections: {
    1: {
      secName: 'def sec name'
    }
  }
};

//So we have an empty object with prototype set to our default object.
var specificObject = Object.create(defaults);


specificObject.sections = {};
console.log(specificObject.hasOwnProperty('sections')); //true

specificObject.sections['1'] = Object.create(defaults.sections['1']);
```

Above code works as expected, but I want to make sure that defaults won't be accidentally changed. So I want to freeze my defaults object:

```
'use strict'
//This object will be prototype of next objects
var defaults = {
  name: 'def name', 
  sections: {
    1: {
      secName: 'def sec name'
    }
  }
};

//!!!!!!!!!!!!
Object.freeze(defaults);

//So we have an empty object with prototype set to our default object.
var specificObject = Object.create(defaults);

//TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'sections' of #<Object>
specificObject.sections = {};
console.log(specificObject.hasOwnProperty('sections')); //true

specificObject.sections['1'] = Object.create(defaults.sections['1']);
```

What I don't get is why can't I assign to specificObject if its prototype is frozen?

//EDIT:
Notice that specific object is not frozen:

```
'use strict'
//This object will be prototype of next objects
var protoObj = {a: 1, o: {}};
Object.freeze(protoObj);

console.log(Object.isFrozen(protoObj)); //true

var n = Object.create(protoObj);
console.log(Object.isFrozen(n)); //false
```

Comment: Maybe because if a prototype is frozen then it's read only.You can not make any changes to it

Comment: that is the whole point of Object.freeze - to prevent any modifications on it.

Comment: The OP is trying to modify inheriting object, and not the prototype.

Comment: specificObject.__proto__ points to prototype which is defaults which is frozen

Comment: You have created `specificObject` using the frozen object. So, it's prototype is frozen and you are trying to modify the frozen property. How do you think it will work ?

Comment: This line: `specificObject.sections = {};` is trying to create a new property in `specificObject` and not modify its prototype.

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu Like in the code without Object.freeze, I'm expecting that sections will be own property on "specificObject".

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I'm freezing defaults object, not the new object returned from Object.create!

Comment: @MarcoBonelli the `specificObject` is not frozen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I don't get is why can't I assign to `specificObject` if its prototype is frozen?

Because property attributes are inherited. Yes, it's odd.

If you freeze an object, it will set the `[[writable]]` attribute of all data properties to `false`.

If you assign to an object property, but that property does not exist on the object, it will go and look it up on the prototype - it might be defined as setter there. When this lookup will return and say that there is a property of that name but it is non-writable, your assignment will fail (and throw in strict mode).

What can you do against this?

- Use `Object.defineProperty` instead of assignment, it doesn't check the prototype
- or similarly, use the second parameter of `Object.create` to create the own property
- freeze the `defaults` only after you've assigned to `specificObject`.

Comment: Is this covered by some specs? It seems that both V8 and Firefox behave this way indeed.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek: Yes, [`Put`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.5) does call [`CanPut`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.4) which does exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

my understanding is that `specificObject.sections` is pointing to its' prototype which is `defaults` and it is frozen object. You define a new object `{}` but you try to assign it to `defaults.sections`. `SpecificObject.sections` is pointing exactly there.

If you create new `ownProperty` on specificObject it will work:

```
'use strict'
//This object will be prototype of next objects
var defaults = {
  name: 'def name',
  sections: {
    1: {
      secName: 'def sec name'
    }
  }
};

//!!!!!!!!!!!!
Object.freeze(defaults);

//So we have an empty object with prototype set to our default object.
var specificObject = Object.create(defaults);

// this will create new property
Object.defineProperty(specificObject, 'sections',{
    enumerable: true,
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    value: {}
});
console.log(specificObject.hasOwnProperty('sections')); //true

specificObject.sections['1'] = Object.create(defaults.sections['1']);
```

explanation:

if you try to access `obj.prop = val` then javascript looks into `obj`'s own properties, if not found then it looks into `obj`'s prototype own properties. if found there then it /tries to assign `val` to/ lookup that property. if not found there then it tries to look into `obj`'s prototype's prototype and so on. If  `prop` is not found in the `prototype` tree then it creates **new own property** on `obj` and assigns `val`.

Therefore if `prop` is find on prototype and it is frozen you will get type error. Hope it brings some light.:)

EDIT:

as correctly pointed out by @KubaWyrostek `specificObj.sections = {}` will create new own property of specific Object, does not assign new value to the prototype's property, but it probably does the lookup for the property to check the writability, in that case it will run into frozen object. I didn't know about this before.

Comment: I like your answer and it solves my problem, but it still does not explain why it tries to modify sections on prototype, not on specific object.

Comment: So it seems that `Object.defineProperty(x, 'y', …)` is using different mechanism than `x['y'] = …`. In the second case the prototype is still involved?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek I added explanation how the property is accessed.

Comment: Thanks, but this statement: "if found there then it tries to assign val to that property" is imho not true. Consult: http://jsfiddle.net/mw9xv0oy/

Comment: @KubaWyrostek, you're right. it is a bit inconsistent.