# Why would an Object prototype method override String and Number prototype methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-chain

Trying to define a `hashCode` method on `Object.prototype` as well as `String.prototype` and `Number.prototype`.  I'm defining the prototype methods using:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'hashCode', {
  value:function() {/*code*/},
  enumerable:false
});

String.prototype.hashCode = function() {/*code*/};
Number.prototype.hashCode = function() {/*code*/};
```

When I create a number or string with any of (`''`, `new String()`, `3`, `new Number()`), and call `hashCode` on the instance, the `Object.prototype.hashCode` method always runs instead of `String.prototype.hashCode` or `Number.prototype.hashCode`.

What's wrong?

Comment: FYI, if I also define the String and Number prototype methods using `Object.defineProperty(String.prototype...` then it works as expected.  The fact that it doesn't work the same way as using `String.prototype.hashCode = function() ...` has me confused.

Comment: Make the property descriptor `writable: true` or it will be inherited as non-writable when writing that property on objects that inherit it. https://jsfiddle.net/5ox1a0f2/

Comment: Oh, cool.  I didn't realize it was not writable by default . Thanks!

Comment: Closely related discussion of this `writable` behavior: [Does Javascript writable descriptor prevent changes on instances?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177663/does-javascript-writable-descriptor-prevent-changes-on-instances)

Comment: Indeed.  It's also interesting that if I set String.prototype.hashCode and Number.prototype.hashCode *before* I call `Object.defineProperty(Object.prorotype...` the functions work as expected, so if you create them, then make them non-writable on Object.prototype, they've already been written and don't lose their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the property descriptor writable: true or it will be inherited as non-writable when writing that property on objects that inherit it. 
http://jsfiddle.net/5ox1a0f2 – squint

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'hashCode', {
  value:function() {console.log('object')},
  enumerable:false,
  writable:true
});

String.prototype.hashCode = function() {console.log('string')};
Number.prototype.hashCode = function() {console.log('number')};

4..hashCode()
```

Comment: Note `String.prototype.hashCode` and `Number.prototype.hashCode` will be enumerable.

Comment: Love the double-dot call on the number literal.  I was getting syntax errors in testing when trying to call '3.hashCode()' but '3..hashCode()' is a nice trick.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing property definitions and property assignments can lead to this kind of problems.

It works if you also use property definition in `String.prototype` and `Number.prototype`:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'hashCode', {
  value: function() {console.log('object')},
  enumerable: false
});
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'hashCode', {
  value: function() {console.log('string')},
  enumerable: false
});
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'hashCode', {
  value: function() {console.log('number')},
  enumerable: false
});
(4).hashCode(); // "number"
('').hashCode(); // "string"
```

However, if you are only using property definitions because you don't want enumerability, but don't care about configurability nor writability, it may be more convenient to define the methods via assignment, and then redefine the enumerability:

```js
Object.prototype.hashCode = function() {console.log('object')};
String.prototype.hashCode = function() {console.log('string')};
Number.prototype.hashCode = function() {console.log('number')};
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'hashCode', {enumerable: false});
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'hashCode', {enumerable: false});
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'hashCode', {enumerable: false});
(4).hashCode(); // "number"
('').hashCode(); // "string"
```